# Error launching android studio says no jvm installed

Tags: java, android-studio, jvm, environment-variables, java-home

I have installed Android studio on windows 64 bit.

When I try to open the application I get a pop up message saying " no JVM installation found. Please install a 64 bit JDK. If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables. 
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHNth.png)

I have installed following JDK

> Java SE Development Kit 8u102
>   Windows x86

I have defined JAVA_HOME in environment variables
[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK72I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `PATH` system variable:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`

That's what I currently have alongside what you have.

EDIT: You have a 32-bit (x86) JDK installed. Make sure to install a 64-bit JDK. The path for that should be

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`

Comment: Did you make sure to add a semicolon before adding this path, and at the end? @VishnuErive

Comment: @VishnuErive. It's important not to have any missing semi-colons. Can you print your PATH system variable? Also make sure to add it to your user variable (the top box).

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin" this is the location i have entered in PATH

Comment: You have `1.8.0_92` in your path. Replace the `92` with `102` @VishnuErive

Comment: I have installed the other version also. Because in my other pc, previously android studio was working fine. In that it has the other version of java i.e 92. installed so i tried here. But it's not working here

Comment: In "here", what is your path variable?

Comment: Variable is "PATH"

Comment: And what is the value of that variable, 'here'? @VishnuErive

Comment: its value is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin"

Comment: @VishnuErive Then you **have** to either: Change `92` to `102`, or **add** `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin` so you have both versions in your PATH.

Comment: Do I have to Create another PATH variable

Comment: @VishnuErive No. You add both versions to your current path variable because you have both versions installed. For example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`

Comment: It's not working.Again it shows the same error message

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin

Comment: @VishnuErive I just noticed you have installed a 32-bit JDK (x86). You don't have a 64-bit installed.

Comment: Thank you. Can you send the link of the 64 bit java

Comment: Both the java and java development kit

Comment: @VishnuErive [JRE for the 8u102](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u102-b14/jre-8u102-windows-x64.exe), and the [JDK 8u102](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u102-b14/jdk-8u102-windows-x64.exe). If this answer helped you, make sure to click the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I just started learning android studio. If need a help at any point of time. How can i reach you. If it's possible for you.

Comment: @VishnuErive e-mail me at calderonj@calderonj.com and we'll go from there.